# How to show suggestions drop down before user has started typing in search?

Tags: android

I have created a content provider and search configuration that work fine. When a user types, it queries my sqlite database and shows suggestions exactly as I'd expect.

So far, so good.

My problem/question is that I would like the system to call the query() function on the content provider immediately upon entering search mode, NOT waiting for the user to start typing. This is because I would like to show a custom list of suggestions immediately upon entering search mode (exactly like the Google Play app works).

I'm using Action Bar Sherlock and have noticed that the query() function IS called on pre-ICS devices exactly as I'd like, but NOT called on ICS+ devices.

Any guesses or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382857/how-to-launch-suggestions-immediately-in-android-searchable-before-the-user-has

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch suggestions immediately in Android searchable before the user has even started typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382857/how-to-launch-suggestions-immediately-in-android-searchable-before-the-user-has)